# terraform throwing "invalid or unknown key: zones" when creating azure vm

Tags: azure, terraform

i am using a key called "zones" while creating an azure vm using the resource "azurerm_virtual_machine". I am using terraform version 0.11.13.
According to the docs, "zones" key is allowed.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html

But when i run "terraform plan", i see the following error:
Error: azurerm_virtual_machine.testVM[4]: : invalid or unknown key: zones

Verified if i am using the key "zones" for the correct resource type and it looks okay according to hashicorp  docs

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "testVM" {
  <code to create VM>
  zones                         = ["1"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update your azurerm provider to the latest version. this is not something terraform handles directly, resource provider does that. I think you could do that by deleting the "internal" tf folder and running `tf init`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I updated azurerm provider and deleted the ".terraform" directory. Then i ran init and plan again. I don't see the issue now.